# How to use SSL in Square MockWebServer?

Tags: android, ssl, https, square, mockwebserver

**I try to enable SSL on [Square's MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)** to mock all webservice calls in my Android App under Test. I want to enable SSL to get the same errors like under real conditions. I don't want to disable SSL for the tests or implement a SSL-ignoring HTTPClient.

On every request I get this **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedExceptionecxeption**:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:42451/api/blabla": No peer certificate; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

It seems I need to set a certificate for the MockWebServer. But I don't know how...

This is how I tried to enable SSL:

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SslContextBuilder(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()).build();
server.useHttps(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), true);
```

Or:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
server.useHttps(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), false);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

You will need to create your own keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore mystore.keystore.jks -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

or see : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

After creating the keystore, load it in your code and use it in the following way:

```
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("mystore.keystore.jks");
        char[] serverKeyStorePassword = "yourcode".toCharArray();
        KeyStore serverKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        serverKeyStore.load(stream, serverKeyStorePassword);

        String kmfAlgorithm = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kmfAlgorithm);
        kmf.init(serverKeyStore, serverKeyStorePassword);

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(kmfAlgorithm);
        trustManagerFactory.init(serverKeyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocketFactory sf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        mockWebServer.useHttps(sf, false);
```

Comment: An important detail for this to work: you must also provide the correct options to the `keytool` command, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118072/2291104

Answer (score 2):

You can use the helpers from [okhttp-tls](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/052a73d3abe536c0f04b5c7b04d35123cc2500a8/okhttp-tls/README.md) to generate a localhost certificate and use it for both your `MockWebServer` and `OkHttpClient`:

> Approachable APIs for using TLS.
>
> A [`HeldCertificate`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-handshake-certificates/) is a certificate and its private key. Use the
> builder to create a self-signed
> certificate that a test server can use for HTTPS:
>
> ```java
> String localhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getCanonicalHostName();
> HeldCertificate localhostCertificate = new HeldCertificate.Builder()
>    .addSubjectAlternativeName(localhost)
>    .build();
> ```
>
> [`HandshakeCertificates`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-held-certificate/) keeps the certificates for a TLS handshake.
> Use its builder to define which
> certificates the HTTPS server returns to its clients. The returned
> instance can create an `SSLSocketFactory` that implements this policy:
>
> ```java
> HandshakeCertificates serverCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
>     .heldCertificate(localhostCertificate)
>     .build();
> MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
> server.useHttps(serverCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), false);
> server.start();
> ```
>
> [`HandshakeCertificates`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-held-certificate/) also works for clients where its job is to
> define which root certificates to trust. In this simplified example we
> trust the server's self-signed certificate:
>
> ```java
> andshakeCertificates clientCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
>     .addTrustedCertificate(localhostCertificate.certificate())
>     .build();
> OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
>     .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager())
>     .build();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this as stated [here](https://adambennett.dev/2021/09/mockwebserver--https/) is to do the following:

First create a self signed CERTIFICATE and PRIVATE KEY and add them to the project. One file should contain both the CERTIFICATE and PRIVATE KEY, this is to be used with MockWebServer. The other contains just the CERTIFICATE, this is to be used in the network security config.

```
val localhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getCanonicalHostName()
val localhostCertificate = HeldCertificate.Builder()
    .addSubjectAlternativeName(localhost)
    .duration(10 * 365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
    .build()
// Print public key
println(localhostCertificate.certificatePem())
// Print private key
println(localhostCertificate.privateKeyPkcs8Pem())
```

Add the cert to the network security config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/debug_cert"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Then use the cert with MockWebServer

```
    val localhostCertificate =
        HeldCertificate.decode("instrumentation_cert.pem".loadString())

    val serverCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .heldCertificate(localhostCertificate)
        .build()

    server.useHttps(
        serverCertificates.sslSocketFactory(),
        tunnelProxy = false,
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how i do it:

```
 MockWebServer serverForHttps = new MockWebServer();
 serverForHttps .useHttps(SslContextBuilder.localhost().getSocketFactory(), false);
 serverForHttps .start()
```

It works for me .

Comment: I always get this error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate`

Comment: For future readers: `SslContextBuilder` is a class, that dynamically generates in-memory certificate during test execution using BouncyCastle. That class used to be present in okhttp source code in the past, but no longer seems to be there. With a bit of effort you can find it's older versions, such as [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/5f7fde35d881e7e9f8850daeac4de52265635656/src/test/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/SslContextBuilder.java).

Comment: I get: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for KeyPairGenerator.RSA.