# Handshake failure with mockwebserver using self signed certificate

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, okhttp, mockwebserver

I am looking to write integration testing of OkHttpClient with a mockwebserver with ssl using an android app. I was able to use HeldCertificate and HandshakeCertificates to achieve this, but I am interested in using self signed certs. While trying with self signed cert, I am getting a handshake failure. Here are the details to reproduce this.

a. Created self signed certificate using this command

`openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key   -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256   -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")`

b. Converted to der for android.
openssl x509 -in localhost.crt -outform der -out localhost.der.crt

c. Fetched the SSLSocketFactory using the code given here: https://gist.github.com/erickok/7692592 to pass it to mockWebserver.useHttps() and OkHttpClientBuilder..sslSocketFactory().

Encountering handshake failure when trying to send and receive a very simple request.

`I/MockWebServer(16935): MockWebServer[38515] connection from null failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
I/System.out(16935): TEMP: 7. Exception thrown javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xeef2cd80: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
I/System.out(16935): error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xee9c4b80:0x00000001)
I/System.out(16935): error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:771 0xea1a6827:0x00000000) Handshake failed
W/System.err(16935): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
W/System.err(16935):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:441)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:337)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:297)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:178)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:272)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
W/System.err(16935):    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
W/System.err(16935):    at com.xyz.okhttp3_abc.sample.test.SampleUiTest.setup(SampleUiTest.java:180)
W/System.err(16935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
W/System.err(16935):    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
W/System.err(16935):    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
W/System.err(16935):    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
W/System.err(16935):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1959)
W/System.err(16935): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xeef2cd80: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err(16935): error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xee9c4b80:0x00000001)
W/System.err(16935): error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:771 0xea1a6827:0x00000000)
W/System.err(16935):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err(16935):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
W/System.err(16935):    ... 55 more
I/TestRunner(16935): failed: simpleTest[0](com.xyz.okhttp3_abc.sample.test.SampleUiTest)
I/TestRunner(16935): failed: simpleTest[0](com.xyz.okhttp3_abc.sample.test.SampleUiTest)
I/TestRunner(16935): ----- begin exception -----
I/TestRunner(16935): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
I/TestRunner(16935):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:441)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:337)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:297)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:178)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:272)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at com.xyz.okhttp3_abc.sample.test.SampleUiTest.setup(SampleUiTest.java:180)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
I/TestRunner(16935):    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor
I/TestRunner(16935): ----- end exception -----
I/TestRunner(16935): finished: simpleTest[0](com.xyz.okhttp3_abc.sample.test.SampleUiTest)
I/MonitoringInstr(16935): Activities that are still in CREATED to STOPPED: 0`

Comment: I know nothing about OkHttpClient but the error string `HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO` seems to say that the problem was with the `ClientHello` message, and this message has no data about certificates since those happen later in another message. ClientHello contains data about local time, a random value, list of cipher suites, compression methods and extensions supported. So maybe there is a problem more around cipher suites.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73793480/875657